# zend_search_lucene rebuild index

Tags: zend-framework, search, lucene, reindex

I'm wondering if anybody can suggest the right way to re-index with zend_search_lucene. There isn't an option to update documents, you need to delete and re-add. I've got a bunch of database tables which I'm going to cycle over and add a document to the index for each. I can't see any point in deleting documents as I go - I may as well empty the entire index, and then add everything afresh.

There doesn't seem to be a simple deleteAllDocs() method, so I have to find them all first, and then loop over them, delete them one by one, then loop over my database tables and add them all. There isn't a getAllDocuments method either (although there is a solution here http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=9121)

Obviously I could write something fancy which checks if the document has changed, and only delete it if it has, but this involves comparing all fields doesn't it?

I feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: I was wondering if I should create a new index, delete the old one and rename. But there isn't obvious ways of deleting and re-naming. As I understand it, this is what the commit does anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I delete the index and create a new index. more or less as [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.index-creation.html)